# Why isn't my program that converts decimal to binary printing correctly?

Tags: c, eclipse

I have an assignment that is asking me to convert a decimal number to its 16-bit 2's complement binary representation stored in a char array. I was provided started code that included a complete main method and an `addOne` method. I just needed to complete the `flipBits` and `magnitudeToBinary` methods.

I have completed the methods and they should work, but I am getting string output. An example is:

```
Enter integers and convert it to 2's complement binary.
Non-numeric input terminates program.
27
Integer: 27, 2's complement binary:
```

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void magnitudeToBinary(int n, char arr[], int numOfBits);
void flipBits(char arr[], int numOfBits);
void addOne(char arr[], int numOfBits);


int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    //Declare a char array with size 16 to simulate 16-bit binary
    int numOfBits = 16;
    char arr[numOfBits + 1];
    arr[numOfBits] = '\0'; //set the terminating character
    //Declare integer n to hold the decimal integer
    int n = 0;

    puts("Enter integers and convert it to 2's complement binary.");
    puts("Non-numeric input terminates program.");

    //Continually taking input and convert it to binary
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {//if successfully read in ONE decimal integer
        //Initialize the char array to all 0s (leave the terminating character unchanged)
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i ++){
            arr[i] = '0';
        }

        //Convert magnitude (absolute value) to binary
        magnitudeToBinary(abs(n), arr, numOfBits);

        //if the number is negative: flip all bits, then add 1.
        if(n < 0){
            //Flip all bits in char arr
            flipBits(arr, numOfBits);
            //Add 1
            addOne(arr, numOfBits);
        }
        //Output binary:
        printf("Integer: %d, 2's complement binary: %s\n", n, arr);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
/* addOne: arithmatically add 1 to the binary simulated by character array
 * INPUT:   char arr[]: the character array holding the binary
 *          int numOfBits: the number of bits in the binary
 * */
void addOne(char arr[], int numOfBits){
    /* True table
     * ******************************
     * carry arr[i] |  arr[i] carry
     *  1       0   |   1       0
     *  1       1   |   0       1
     *  0       0   |   0       0
     *  0       1   |   1       0
     * *********************************/
    char carry = '1';
    for(int i = numOfBits - 1; i >= 0; i --){
        if(carry != arr[i]){
            arr[i] = '1';
            carry = '0';
        }
        else if(carry == '1'){
            arr[i] = '0';
        }
        else{
            arr[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    return;
}
/* flipBits: perform 1's complement on the binary, i.e., change 1 to 0, 0 to 1
 * INPUT:   char arr[]: the character array holding the binary
 *          int numOfBits: the number of bits in the binary *
 * */
void flipBits(char arr[], int numOfBits){
    //Implement your solution here
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == '1') {
            arr[i] = '0';
        } else if(arr[i] == '0') {
            arr[i] = '1';
        }
    }
    return;
}
/* magnitudeToBinary:   Convert a non-negative decimal integer to binary (stored in a char array)
 *                      using division-remainder algorithm
 * INPUT:   int n: The decimal integer number to be converted
 *          char arr[]: the character array holding the binary
 *          int numOfBits: the number of bits in the binary *
 * */
void magnitudeToBinary(int n, char arr[], int numOfBits){
    //Implement the division-remainder algorithm here
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        arr[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

I would just like to see the correct binary output. Right now I am unsure if it is an error on my part, my professor's, or if Eclipse is acting up. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The `magnitudeToBinary` function looks very fishy to me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky lol! Any ideas why? Ever heard of the division-remainder thingy for converting decimal to binary? I hate it

Comment: `arr[i] = n % 2;` should be `arr[i] = n % 2 + '0';`. That would do.

Comment: You're mixing up numbers and ASCII codes.

Comment: Actually you don't need the _division-remainder thingy_, because the numbers are already in binary and you can directly access the bits using shift operations and mask operations.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ? I need that method for the assignment

Comment: @Yonlif I will try that

Comment: Inside the fishy function, the parameter `numOfBits` is ignored, it could be used to make sure not to write beyond the receiving array. Writing beyond it would be UB, undefined behaviour, i.e. a bad thing (tm).

Comment: Assume the problem is yours until you've established that it can't be yours.  It's unlikely that your professor has made a mistake.  Not impossible, just unlikely.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you. I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line in magnitudeToBinary() from :

```
    arr[i] = n % 2;
```

to

```
    arr[i] = n % 2 == 1 ? '1' : '0';
```

You want to write the ASCII value for '1' or '0' into the array - not the result of n % 2.

Comment: It now prints! I don't believe it is printing the right binary, but I think I will ask another question in regards to that if I can't figure it out on my own, thanks for your help!

Comment: It’s probably printing the digits in reverse order, @HelanaBrock.  You put the least significant digit in the first (zeroth) place, not the last.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler awesome, thank you! I believe I just fixed that. In the case of -27, the 8-bit output would be 11100101. For 16-bit my program is printing 1111111111100101 which has the last 8 bits right but I am unsure if the rest are supposed to be 1's as well? It's doing this for all negative numbers

Comment: Leading digits mostly ones is normal for a negative number of small magnitude, such as -27.   Bigger magnitude numbers have fewer leading ones.  Small positive numbers have mostly leading zeros, of course; larger ones have fewer.  It’s the converse for negative numbers. @HelanaBrock

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Amazing. Superb. Thank you so much! My professor didn't really tell us this, I guess I should've known, lol. Looks like the program works now. Thanks again, hope you have an incredible day!

Comment: Why don't use `arr[i] = (n % 2 == 1) == true ? '1' : '0';` ? or even better `arr[i] = ((n % 2 == 1) == true) == true ? '1' : '0'` ?

Comment: @LuisColorado yeah, I can see either as better because they make the true/false more clear.